# Hide checkout fields based on selected country Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

If the shipping address is set to a certain country (Jordan) I want several checkout fields to be hidden,
They are the street address and the ZIP code...

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider. Askers are expected to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us the problems they are facing. Please review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site. Goodluck

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this on functions.php:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'woo_conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field', 9999 );

function woo_conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field() {
wc_enqueue_js( "
    // On page load
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // var country_code = jQuery(this).val();
        var country_name = jQuery('#billing_country option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
        show_hide_fields(country_name);
    });

    // On change country dropdown
    jQuery(document).on('change','#billing_country',function() {
        var country_name = jQuery('option:selected',this).text().toLowerCase();
        show_hide_fields(country_name);
    });

    function show_hide_fields(country){
        if (country == 'jordan') {
            jQuery('#billing_address_1_field').hide();
            jQuery('#billing_address_2_field').hide();
            jQuery('#billing_postcode_field').hide();
        } else {
            jQuery('#billing_address_1_field').show();
            jQuery('#billing_address_2_field').show();
            jQuery('#billing_postcode_field').show();
        }
    }
");
}
```

**Remove Required Validation:** (If needed - you can change field value accordingly)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'woo_disable_address_fields_validation' );

function woo_disable_address_fields_validation( $address_fields_array ) {

   unset( $address_fields_array['state']['validate']);
   unset( $address_fields_array['postcode']['validate']);
   // you can also hook first_name and last_name, company, country, city, address_1 and address_2

   return $address_fields_array;

}
```

Now Copy past both functions on your active theme functions.php
You can also manage show/hide fields accordingly and also use country_code as per requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It works great except the fields are required by default and they need to be set as optional.
I tried looking for the code to do it but I cannot figure it out!

Comment: Its Too easy use unset validation for specific fields - see (reference URL - https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/checkout-fields.html)

Comment: Example - add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'misha_disable_address_fields_validation' );

function misha_disable_address_fields_validation( $address_fields_array ) {

 unset( $address_fields_array['state']['validate']);
 unset( $address_fields_array['postcode']['validate']);
 // you can also hook first_name and last_name, company, country, city, address_1 and address_2

 return $address_fields_array;

}

Comment: Thank you for the link! It is really useful. But I am sorry I wasn't clear, I want to combine the two functions. I mean I want to hide the state and zip code ONLY if Jordan is selected but keep it required for other countries.

I am not sure how to integrate the original code you kindly wrote with the hiding of the fields. (The original code only hides them but they are still required, and the new code hides them for all countries which is also incorrect)

Comment: Now I have updated my answer so you can easily understand what I was saying.